Edited tags in tag edits don't show up in the edit history page if the tag has been deleted
Example: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/142483/revisions

Edited tags in edits 2 and 3 aren't displayed (I added red arrows to point to their absence). I believe it is because the tag was later deleted.
